# Cordova in Visual Studio - without Internet Connection

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, npm

I'm starting to develop a Cordova application using Visual Studio 2015.
The computer is connected to the corporate's firewall which blocks almost everything...

When I try to build the application, there are many internet requests (such as NPM install).

Is there a way to develop Cordova applications using Visual Studio without relying on full internet connection?

Comment: There is probably a way but it would require you getting *all* the required packages on to your dev machine which would be very difficult as you would have to figure out each package's dependencies too.

Answer (score 0):

TACO has a "build offline" scenario described in the developer blog-- http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/06/16/build-offline.html.

Disclosure--I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team.